# PHP Login for Customer and Admin

Tags: php, authentication, admin

I am trying to develop a login system where both a customer and admin can login. The customer will be sent back to the index and the admin will be sent to a control panel. I have a user table in my database. Here a have level which defines the users; customer level = 1 and admin level = 0.

I am reletavily new to PHP and have been searching the internet for answers. I have found two versions of what i need. I'm not 100% sure they are correct and which is the best to use.

**Example 1:**

```
//indicate that sessions are to be used or started

session_start();


 // Define $myusername and $mypassword from the form

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 

$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// Query

$result= $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword';");

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row

$count = $result->rowCount();

// Determine if user is "user" or "admin"

$userlevel =  mysqli_query($con,"SELECT level FROM users WHERE username='$myusername';");
$level = mysql_fetch_row($userlevel);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1) {

// Start session, register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to login_success.php

session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
$_SESSION['level'] = $level;

// Redirect to appropriate page depending on user rights. Indicator 0 for user, 1 for admin.

if($_SESSION['level'] == 0)
{
    //Admin Login
    header("location:../php/admin.php"); 

}
 if ($_SESSION['level']) == 1)

 {
//Customer login

    header("location:../login_success.php");
    }

//flush the output buffer

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

**Example 2:**

```
// Define $myusername and $mypassword from the form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 



$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword' and level== '0'";

if($count==1){
  $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
  $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
  $info = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if ($info['level'] == 0) {
        header("location:../php/admin.php");
    }
    else
        header("location:../index.html");
    }
}
else {
    echo "Incorrect password";
}
?>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Both have serious errors and vulnerabilities (such as, but probably not limited to, sql injection and plain text passwords. Perhaps investigate a lightweight well documented framework that will have built in methods for this

Comment: I have protected against SQL injection (just didn't include it in the code here). I just want the log in system to work. This is only for a test website.

Answer (score 0):

Both lots of code work in the same way. The second code block looks a lot cleaner.

Though, there is other problems, your query has 0 protection from injection. And these days it's good practice to use PDO for database connections.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Also, while the headers are fine, you need to check on the admin page to make sure they are an administrator. And make sure to Hash their password and compare against the hash. Also don't store the password in the session.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd one seems a lot nicer to be fair, I've got some old stuff modified from when I learned in school, so it's most likely not the best way of doing it, but it does work if you do want to take anything from it.

(as the guy said above - definitely do some validation on the values before using them in the database)

```
$username=$_POST['myusername']; 
$password=$_POST['mypassword'];

#very simple checks
if(!preg_match("#^[A-Za-z0-9_ ]*$#",$username) or !preg_match("#^[A-Za-z0-9 _.,\-\@]*$#",$password)){
    $fail="No matching records found";
}
else if(empty($username) or empty($password)){
    $fail="All fields are required";
}
else{
    #search for user
    $sql="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='".$username."' AND Password ='".$password."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);
    if($num==1){
        #get values
        while ($login = mysql_fetch_row($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) { 
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            if($row['level'])==0){
                $_SESSION['admin'] = True;
                header("location:../php/admin.php");
            }
            else{
                $_SESSION['admin'] = False;
                header("location:../login_success.php");
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $fail = "No matching records found";
    }
}
```